# Magento 2: How to group and make new sections in customer attributes in Account Information Tab?

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, admin-panel, customer-attribute

I want to sort and group Customer Attributes in back-office view. There is no problem with sorting but how can I group it? There is no Attribute Set/Groups like for product attributes. I want to make a few sections in this view. What is the best way to do it? [image]

Comment: you want to group your custom attributes or predefined customer attributes

Comment: I need to group all of them,  but mainly custom attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Create file customer_form.xml in Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

  <fieldset name="customer">   
    <fieldset name="test">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Tab</item>
               <item name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">100</item>
               <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
       <field name="field1">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Field 1</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </field>
     </fieldset>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

[image]

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Do you think it is possible to add existing attributes to this fieldset named test? instead of creating new ones (FIeld1)

Comment: yes you can just mention their name in the field name